# How to Iterate the Terms using Termset Id in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, term-store, term, term-set

I need to Iterate the terms using Termset ID, I Tried

```
TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
                        TermStore termstore = taxonomySession.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;

                        TermSet breadcrumbTermSet = termstore.GetTermSet(new Guid("fdc98309-c520-44eb-a5ca-f2a04d8dd541"));
                        var terms = breadcrumbTermSet.Terms;
                        var siteCollectionURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
                        var requestURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
                        string termSetName = "", termName = "";

                        foreach (var parentTerm in terms)
                        {
                            if (parentTerm.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"] == siteCollectionURL.ToString())
                            {
                                termSetName = " / &nbsp" + parentTerm.Name;
                            }
                            foreach (var childTerm in parentTerm.Terms)
                            {
                                if (parentTerm.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"] == requestURL.ToString())
                                {
                                    termSetName = " / &nbsp" + childTerm.Name;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

But I can't, I need more Reference about this, can you please suggest some Idea to achieve this

Comment: Can you let me know the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# Server object model, you can try it as below:

```
TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
TermStore termstore = taxonomySession.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;

Guid termSetGuid = new Guid("fdc98309-c520-44eb-a5ca-f2a04d8dd541");

TermSet breadcrumbTermSet = termstore.GetTermSet(termSetGuid);
TermCollection terms = breadcrumbTermSet.GetAllTerms();
var siteCollectionURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
var requestURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
string termSetName = "", termName = "";

foreach (var parentTerm in terms)
{
    if (parentTerm.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"] == siteCollectionURL.ToString())
    {
        termSetName = " / &nbsp" + parentTerm.Name;
    }
    foreach (var childTerm in parentTerm.Terms)
    {
        if (parentTerm.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"] == requestURL.ToString())
        {
            termSetName = " / &nbsp" + childTerm.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple options you can try.

1. You can call `TermSet.GetAllTerms()` method to return all terms under that TermSet.
2. Another approach you can try is to use recursive function to enumerate `termSet.Terms` and `term.Terms`

I list the code for approach 1 at the following. You can check `term.PathOfTerm` to find out the term's hierarchy information.

```
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
    }
    private static void Test()
    {
        string url = "http://sp1:1111";
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url))
        {
            TaxonomySession session = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(context);
            TermStore store = session.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
            TermSet termSet = store.GetTermSet(new Guid("6e17ec6e-7456-4e61-82e9-d5a75f6932fa"));
            TermCollection terms = termSet.GetAllTerms();
            context.Load(terms);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach(Term term in terms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(term.PathOfTerm);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```